# Is there a quick method on linux to switch to recently accessed n folders (n > 1)?

Tags: linux, directory

We can use `cd -` to access the most recently accessed folder, but what if I want to quickly switch to the last but one folder accessed?

Comment: no there isn't : https://ss64.com/bash/cd.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure there's a way!
You want the shell builtin `pushd`.

```
[~]$ pwd
/home/dan
[~]$ pushd /tmp
/tmp ~
[tmp]$ pushd /usr/bin
/usr/bin /tmp ~
[bin]$ pushd +2
~ /usr/bin /tmp
[~]$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -t | head -n1
```

Above command use to get most recently used directory

Comment: I don't think this is correct. From the ls man page: `-t     sort by modification time, newest first`